# indexPath returns 0 in all rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a `tableView` with only 1 section and it keep returning 0 in all `indexPath.Row`. What am I doing wrong? here is me logging the `indexPath`

#### NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

```
<NSIndexPath: 0xd2897d0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
<NSIndexPath: 0xd290af0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}
<NSIndexPath: 0xd2a5cd0> {length = 2, path = 2 - 0}
<NSIndexPath: 0xd2a8340> {length = 2, path = 3 - 0}
```

#### cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;


    if (indexPath.row < 3) {
        TextFieldTableViewCell *accountCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: textFieldCellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];
        accountCell.cellTextField.delegate = self;

            accountCell.cellLabel.text = [accountArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {


        accountCell.cellTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {


            accountCell.cellTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {


            accountCell.cellTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        }

        cell = accountCell;


    } else if (indexPath.row == 3) {

        ACEExpandableTextCell *textViewCell = [tableView expandableTextCellWithId:@"cellId"];
        textViewCell.text = [self.cellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        textViewCell.textView.placeholder = @"Placeholder";
        cell = textViewCell;

    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What code do you have for `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: that happens if you create new section for each row.

Comment: This is because you likely mixed up the numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection - the output you provided indicates you have 4 sections and 1 row in each.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem could be this

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [arry count];
}   
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    return 1;
    }
```

instead

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    return [arry count];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may swapped the return value of `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`

If this is correct, the below log will give you an idea.

```
 NSLog(@"Section Number %d", indexPath.section);
 NSLog(@"Row Number %d", indexPath.row);
```

This will log the row numbers as per the section.

Example: If you have a TableView with 2 sections and 6 rows (3 rows in each section),this will log as

```
Section Number 0
Row Number 0
Section Number 0
Row Number 1
Section Number 0
Row Number 2

Section Number 1
Row Number 0
Section Number 1
Row Number 1
Section Number 1
Row Number 2
```

Answer (score 0):

May be because of you not created object of UITableViewCell and not allocated.
please lookup bellow code once.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    //Here add your stuffs
}
```

And also check numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection UITableView Delegate methods.

Regards.